# How to get httrack to work with SSL on mac os x?  (libssl.so not found)

Tags: mac-osx, package-management, openssl

I'm trying to use httrack website copier but the program is running and reporting "no-ssl" (ie: it does not have the capability to copy secure sites).

From looking over [this thread](http://forum.httrack.com/readmsg/14979/14946/index.html), it seems that the problem is either when I make & configure the program, or when I run the program, it is not finding the lib-ssl / open-ssl that I have installed. I think it is looking for `/var/root/lib/libssl.so.1.0`

The user on that forum states that he created a symlink which allowed httrack to find the ssl library in the non-default location. Perhaps that's what I need to do - but where do I create the link from and to? I'm not seeing that I have any `libssl.so` files installed on my system. Do I need the development package? If so, how do I install that? I used macports to install the current version of openssl that I have. I'm running OS X 10.6.

#### Reserch

I have run this command to try and debug:

```
dtruss httrack 2>&1 | grep ssl
```

and that outputs this:

```
stat64("libssl.so.1.0\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEE30, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("/var/root/lib/libssl.so.1.0\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.0\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF220, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("libssl.so.1\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEE30, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/var/root/lib/libssl.so.1\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF220, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF220, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/lib/libssl.so.1\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF220, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("libssl.so.1.0.0\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEE30, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/var/root/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF220, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("libssl.so.0\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEE30, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/var/root/lib/libssl.so.0\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF220, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/lib/libssl.so.0\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF220, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/lib/libssl.so.0\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF220, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("libssl.so.0.9\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEE30, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("/var/root/lib/libssl.so.0.9\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/lib/libssl.so.0.9\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF220, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("libssl.so.0.9.8p\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEE30, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("/var/root/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8p\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8p\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8p\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF220, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("libssl.so.0.9.8o\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEE30, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("/var/root/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8o\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8o\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8o\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF220, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("libssl.so.0.9.8n\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEE30, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("/var/root/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8n\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8n\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8n\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF220, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("libssl.so.0.9.8m\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEE30, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("/var/root/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8m\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8m\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8m\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF220, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("libssl.so.0.9.8l\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEE30, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("/var/root/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8l\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8l\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8l\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF220, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("libssl.so.0.9.8k\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEE30, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("/var/root/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8k\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8k\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8k\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF220, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("libssl.so.0.9.8j\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEE30, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("/var/root/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8j\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8j\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8j\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF220, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("libssl.so.0.9.8g\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEE30, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("/var/root/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8g\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8g\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8g\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF220, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("libssl.so.0.9.8b\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEE30, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("/var/root/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8b\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8b\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8b\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF220, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("libssl.so.0.9.8\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEE30, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/var/root/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF220, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("libssl.so.0.9.7\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEE30, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/var/root/lib/libssl.so.0.9.7\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/lib/libssl.so.0.9.7\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9.7\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF220, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("libssl.so.0.9.6\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEE30, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/var/root/lib/libssl.so.0.9.6\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/lib/libssl.so.0.9.6\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF210, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9.6\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF220, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("libssl.so\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEE30, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("/var/root/lib/libssl.so\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF220, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/lib/libssl.so\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF220, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/lib/libssl.so\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF220, 0x7FFF5FBFF470)       = -1 Err#2
```

I have already used mac ports to install open-ssl:

```
>> port installed

The following ports are currently installed:
  beecrypt @4.2.1_2 (active)
  cpio @2.10_0 (active)
  expat @2.0.1_1 (active)
  flex @2.5.35_0 (active)
  gettext @0.18.1.1_2 (active)
  gperf @3.0.4_0 (active)
  icu @4.6_0 (active)
  libiconv @1.13.1_0 (active)
  mysql5 @5.1.53_0 (active)
  ncurses @5.9_0 (active)
  ncursesw @5.8_0 (active)
  neon @0.29.5_0 (active)
  openssl @1.0.0c_0 (active)
  perl5.8 @5.8.9_3 (active)
  popt @1.16_0 (active)
  python24 @2.4.6_7 (active)
  readline @6.1.002_0 (active)
  rpm @4.4.9_10 (active)
  sqlite3 @3.7.3_0 (active)
  zlib @1.2.5_0 (active)
```

Here are the install locations:

```
>> locate libssl

/opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
/opt/local/lib/libssl.a
/opt/local/lib/libssl.dylib
/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig/libssl.pc
/opt/local/var/macports/software/openssl/1.0.0c_0/opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
/opt/local/var/macports/software/openssl/1.0.0c_0/opt/local/lib/libssl.a
/opt/local/var/macports/software/openssl/1.0.0c_0/opt/local/lib/libssl.dylib
/opt/local/var/macports/software/openssl/1.0.0c_0/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig/libssl.pc
/usr/lib/libssl.0.9.7.dylib
/usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
/usr/lib/libssl.0.9.dylib
/usr/lib/libssl.dylib
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libssl.pc
```

What should I do next?

#### More Info

I tried the solution below:

```
$ DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="/opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib" httrack

Welcome to HTTrack Website Copier (Offline Browser) 3.44-1-nossl
Copyright (C) Xavier Roche and other contributors
To see the option list, enter a blank line or try httrack --help
```

It is still not able to load the ssl lib:  **3.44-1-nossl**

Comment: MaxOSX (Darwin) is mostly based on FreeBSD + Mach Kernel; it's **not Linux**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When httrack loads, it looks for the openssl library. Because it is designed for linux/unix, it assumes the open ssl library will be called libssl.so and when it is named something different on the mac it can't find it.

Run this command to create a symlink called libssl.so which points to the right file:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libssl.dylib /usr/lib/libssl.so
```

[via](http://forum.httrack.com/readmsg/16331/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt the following:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/local/lib" httrack
```

Or perhaps:

```
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="/opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib" httrack
```

If that doesn't work, please provide the error output from httrack.  Did you build it from source, or download a binary?

Comment: There is no error from httrack, it just runs without the SSL options b/c it can't find it. I did build it from scratch, do you want the build log?